# Play Framework - Upgrade to Web socket manually

Tags: scala, websocket, playframework

Upgrade to web socket is abstracted in play frame work. How to implement that manually ?

I creating a web socket application using play framework.
I can able to establish a connection between a web socket client and the server (that i have created)
But upgrade to web socket has been abstracted by play-framework.

```
def chatSystem(): WebSocket = WebSocket.acceptOrResult[String, String] { request =>
    Future.successful{
      AuthenticationService.doBasicAuthentication(request.headers) match {
        case Results.Ok => Right(ActorFlow.actorRef { out => ChatServiceActor.props(out) })
        case _ => Left(Unauthorized)
      }
    }
  }

URL : ws://localhost:9000/chatSystem/test123
```

I need to do the following things before the connection is established,

If the Websocket-server does not recognize the userId in the URL path, it should send an HTTP response with status 404 and abort the WebSocket connection

If the Websocket-server does not agree to using one of the subprotocols offered by the client, it must complete the Web Socket handshake with a response without a Sec-WebSocket-Protocol header and then immediately close the WebSocket connection.

I am not sure how to implement the logic manually , in order to send upgrade response to client and then establish a web socket 
connection.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I think this is not possible, I was able to detect that the `WebSocket` is a `Handler`, and play expects the methods implementing routes to return a `Handler`, so, in theory, if you can build a method that returns a `Handler` that is a function that transforms a `RequestHeader` to another `Handler` (like `trait CustomHandler extends (RequestHeader => Handler) with Handler`), then, you would be able to create an instance that checks whether the web socket connection should be established.

But, if you do that, you'll get an exception while firing a request, hopefully, there is a crucial detail that I'm missing, I suggest to open a ticket on their github:

My stacktrace is:

```
akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException: Inner flow was completed without producing result elements for 1 outstanding elements
    at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException$.apply(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:22)
    at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException$.apply(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:22)
    at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$One2OneBidi$$anon$1$$anon$4.onUpstreamFinish(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:97)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:504)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:378)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:588)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:472)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:563)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:745)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:760)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:515)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.aroundReceive(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:670)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:588)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:557)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException: Inner flow was completed without producing result elements for 1 outstanding elements
    at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException$.apply(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:22)
    at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$OutputTruncationException$.apply(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:22)
    at akka.http.impl.util.One2OneBidiFlow$One2OneBidi$$anon$1$$anon$4.onUpstreamFinish(One2OneBidiFlow.scala:97)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.processEvent(GraphInterpreter.scala:504)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreter.execute(GraphInterpreter.scala:378)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.runBatch(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:588)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell$AsyncInput.execute(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:472)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.GraphInterpreterShell.processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:563)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter.akka$stream$impl$fusing$ActorGraphInterpreter$$processEvent(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:745)
    at akka.stream.impl.fusing.ActorGraphInterpreter$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ActorGraphInterpreter.scala:760)
```